# Equation has two distinct solutions

Tags: calculus, quadratics, discriminant

We have $\displaystyle{ a,b,c }$ real numbers such that $\displaystyle{ a^2+b^2+c^2>0 }$. Which condition must hold so that the equation $\displaystyle{ ax^2+bx+c=0 }$ has two different solutions?

$$$$

I have done the following :

\begin{align*}&ax^2+bx+c=0 \Rightarrow x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}=0 \text{ if } a\neq 0 \\ &a=0 \Rightarrow ax^2+bx+c=0 \Rightarrow bx+c=0 \Rightarrow x=-\frac{c}{b}\ \text{ In this case we have only one solution, so it must be } a\neq 0\end{align*}

We have that \begin{equation*}x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}=0 \Rightarrow x=-\frac{b}{2a}\pm \sqrt{\left (\frac{b}{2a}\right )^2-\frac{c}{a}}\end{equation*}
We have two different solution if $\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\neq \frac{c}{a}$, i.e. if $b^2\neq 4ac$.

Is the condition correct?

Comment: Has two different solutions in real numbers?

Comment: By itself the condition you got is correct, but you have not used the given condition about the sum of the squares.

Comment: @Prem: That condition merely says that the three values are not all zero. Already if $a = 0$ there cannot be two solutions unless $b$ and $c$ are also zero.

Comment: It is not clarified if the solutions are in real numbers or also in complex. @BrianTung

Comment: Discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$  is non zero.

Comment: In the way I showed it, I don't use the fact that not all three values are zero, do I ? @BrianTung

Comment: So you mean it as I did above, don't you? @SouravGhosh

Comment: $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ . So only way to get two distinct solutions is the discriminant is non zero.

Comment: Is the discriminant is non zero we get two solutions, either real or complex, right? @SouravGhosh

Comment: So we use the given condition that $a^2+b^2+c^2>0$ to show that if $a=0$ we have two solutions only if $b=c=0$, which cannot be true, right? @BrianTung

Answer (score 1):

for any degree two polynomial in order for it to have real roots we must have :
$$\Delta = b^2-4ac > 0$$
and if $\Delta \neq 0$ it always has two distinct solutions real or complex so that I believe suffices.